# wordpress config file key

Tags: wordpress

I have downloaded the worpress from online. The following code is in config.php.

```
define('AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here');
```

Even if i don't define any key my site runs fine. Is it compulsory to define those keys? If i don't define them are they affect my site? Please explain.

Comment: http://www.pixelapes.com/2009/04/30/increasing-your-wordpress-security/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following location you can find the detailed explanation of your question. I hope this helps. Thanks

http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Security_Keys